# How to dynamically extend (add properties to) generic class as argument in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How to express the following code in TypeScript?

```
const enhanceClass = (cls) => {
  cls.prototype.add = (a, b) => a + b;
}
class A {}
enhanceClass(A);
const i = new A()
i.add(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

[TypeScript added support for mixin classes in 2.2.](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/05/26/typescript-2-2-mixin-classes) Try this:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T

function enhanced<T extends Constructor>(Base: T) {
  class WithAdd extends Base {
    add(a: number, b: number) {
      return a + b
    }
  }

  return WithAdd
}

const EnhancedA = enhanced(class A {})

const a = new EnhancedA()
a.add(1, 2)
```

Though it doesn't do the exact same as in your example, I'd argue that mutating the class prototype being passed in is probably not the best practice anyway.

Comment: I guess mutating existing class is not possible in typescript, yet?

Comment: It's _possible_, just not type safe. It probably won't ever get implemented in a mutative way